# React Native: How to use Webview to read video post from Wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, react-native, webview

I am quite new in react native. I am using expo and trying to read data from `WordPress`. But the problem appeared when the post contains a video.

The video is running well but the video size showed inside the is bigger than the screen size.
I have tried `scalesPageToFit={true}`. However, it did not work for me.
Is there any way to solve this issue?

```
const styles = {
  featuredImage: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    width: window.width,
    height: 200
  },
  title: {
    fontFamily: 'roboto-slab-regular',
    fontSize: 20,
    lineHeight: 22,
    marginTop: 16,
    marginHorizontal: 16
  },

    content: {
        flex: 1,
        height: 400, 
        alignItems: 'center'

    },

  meta: {
    marginTop: 16,
    marginHorizontal: 16,

  }
}




export default class Post extends Component {
     webview = null;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            tamanho: 122,
            post: props.post,
         scalesPageToFit: true,

        };
    }

    _postMessage = ( ) => {
        this.webview.postMessage( "Hello" );
        console.log( "Posted message" );
        scalesPageToFit=true
    }

    _receivedMessage = ( e )  => {
        console.log("Received message");
        this.setState( { tamanho: parseInt(e.nativeEvent.data)} );
                scalesPageToFit=true

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._postMessage();
    }



 render() {
        let post = this.state.post;

  let HTML ='<html>' +
                    '<head>' +
                        '<title></title>' +
                    '</head>' +
                    '<body>' +
                        post.content.rendered +
                    '</body>' +
                '</html>';





   let javascript =   'window.location.hash = 1;' +
                            'document.title = document.body.scrollHeight;' +
                            'window.postMessage( document.body.scrollHeight );';

  return (
    <View>
      <PostImage post={post} style={styles.featuredImage} showEmpty />
      <Text style={styles.title}>{entities.decode(post.title.rendered)}</Text>
      <PostMeta style={styles.meta} post={post} />




                        <WebView 
                        scrollEnabled={false}

                            ref={webview => { this.webview = webview; }}
                            injectedJavaScript={javascript}
                            javaScriptEnabled={true}
                            javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
                            onMessage={this._receivedMessage} 
                            scalesPageToFit={true}
                            allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
                            decelerationRate="normal"
                            style={styles.content}
                            automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
                            domStorageEnabled={true}
                            startInLoadingState={true}
                            source={{html: HTML}} 

                             />



    </View>
  );
      }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add the `width` property to fit the webview to device's screen to the `styles` in your `react-native` project.

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
```

Add this below snippet in **styles**

```
content: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    width: deviceWidth,
    height: 400//deviceHeight
  }
```